# reference to 'list' is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I created a list and want to check it's size, like this

```
 1.  list<State> list;  
 2.  list.push_back (state1);
 3.  list.push_back (state2);
 4.  list.push_back (state2);
 5.  int l = list.size();
```

Then I got those error:

```
 "[Error] candidates are: std::list<State> list" in line 1.
 "[Error] reference to 'list' is ambiguous " in line 5.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You probably have two `list`s in the same namespace.

Comment: Decide on which you want for your var name: `list` (which would be odd), or `mylist`, which you seem to have considered at some time in history already. And update your post to have a real [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reflect which *line* the error is actually reported on.

Comment: I am using std namespace. Can you explain more, which are two lists and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to name a variable of class `list` with the same name `list`. Give it some other name and it should be fine.